# Trying to convert ppt to pdf using libreoffice ---headless -convert- topdf with php script

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, conversion, selinux

When used below command on the command line it working file

```
libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf ".$sourse." -outdir outputolder/
```

but, if use in php script nothing happen. Can anybody provide explanation on what is the exact issue with

Answer (score 4):

Well, I can see that you typed "-convert-to pdf" instead of "--convert-to-pdf". Maybe you did a similar typo in your php script? Hard to say without seeing the PHP code, though.

Please provide details: how do you call libreoffice from PHP, what do the error logs say etc.

Finally, if you are running SElinux and not Ubuntu, please take the question to a SELinux forum.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the filter name

This is the general format of convert-to (noting that on windows the parameter is :

`-convert-to` not `--convert-to`

```
soffice --headless --convert-to <TargetFileExtension>:<NameOfFilter> file_to_convert.xxx
```

Use the [link](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/config/fragments/filters) to look for the filter names in the .xcu files.

For example, I wanted to convert to Excel 95 format so I found the MS_Excel_95.xcu filter and inside it has a name:

```
<node oor:name="MS Excel 95" oor:op="replace">
     ...
```

I could then try it out:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to xls:"MS Excel 95" filename.xlsx
```

(I needed this to get a non-xml version of an excel file)

Copied from : [ask.libreOffice.org](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/)

Comment: Please provide your answer in terms of steps and then try to refer a link, because links can expire or move to different location.